# Parse.com do something in cloud code before a scheduled push is sent

Tags: parse-platform

I have scheduled a push notification to be sent with cloud code, and I would like to do something in cloud code before (or directly after) the push is sent, regardless of whether it was received or not.

Any ideas? Is there a Parse.Push.beforeSend() or something along those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create cloudcode function which will do javascript code and then invoke sending of notifications.

Comment: But I would need to put a delay on that function... for example if I wanted to send the push 10 hours from now and do something when it is sent in 10 hours, I would need to have code running and waiting for 10 hours. Parse won't allow code running for over 20 minutes, will it?

Comment: You can store scheduled notification data into table (create class for it in database) and have background job running every N minutes which could check if there is something to be send out at that time, perform the custom code and send it out.